# date and phone number format in php

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to get data from user and store into database using php.  when i add date & phone number , it store any 1st number of date what you entered & any random number in phone number.

```
$fname = $_GET['fname'];
$lname = $_GET['lname'];
$mname = $_GET['mname'];
$dob = $_GET['dob'];
$pnumber = $_GET['pnumber'];
$occupation = $_GET['occupation'];
$joindate = $_GET['join date'];
$ffname = $_GET['ffname'];
$flname = $_GET['flname'];
$peraddress = $_GET['peraddress'];
$fpnumber = $_GET['fpnumber'];
$mpnumber = $_GET['mpnumber'];
$roomnumber = $_GET['roomnumber'];
$deposite = $_GET['deposite'];
//$password = $_GET['password'];
//$sha1password = sha1($password);

//create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'Hostel');

//check connection
if ($connection->connect_error) {
die('Connection error (' . $connection->connect_errno . ') ' .$connection->connect_error);
}

echo 'Cool!' .$connection->host_info . "\n";

 $sqlin = "INSERT INTO Student (First_Name, Last_Name, Middle_Name,   Date_of_Birth, Phone_Number, Occupation, Join_Date, Father_First_Name, Father_Last_Name, Permenent_Address, Father_Phone_Number, Mother_Phone_Number, Room_Number, Deposite)
 VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$mname', '$dob', '$pnumber', '$occupation', '$joindate', '$ffname', '$flname', '$peraddress', '$fpnumber', '$mpnumber', '$roomnumber', '$deposite')";

 if ($connection->query($sqlin) === TRUE) {
 echo"Thank you! Your info has been entered into database";
 }else{
    echo"Error: " . $sqlin . "<br>" . $connection->error;
 }

 $connection->close();

 ?>
```

i already set date type is date in html and for phone number is text.
how i can correct date with any format with calender option and phone number ?

Comment: You should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  It'll help with managing variable types, and also prevent [SQL Injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) that you're completely unprepared for right now.

Comment: Are you passing password through $_GET?

Comment: Hi james , you are right, i am completely for php and sql. can you tell me please how to use PDO with a small code? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Andreas, no i am not passing password from $_GET. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are posting your data from the form using _GET, that might have caused the problem with date when saving in database. Change the form post method to 'POST' and read posted values using $_POST

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but i tried $_POST everywhere and some different places but it didnt worked, at least it worked with $_GET , so i am using $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you mentioned the type of colomn you created as date. It has to be sent only in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' and I don't think it support other format you entered to store and you ca store the telephone number even in text format. you can use strotime() to convert the entered date into that format `$dob1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dob));` so that you could store in database without any errors and you should specify the entire date if you declare the variable to be stored as date in database

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i tried your option but it showing me this error for date.      '1991/5/12 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(1991/5/12));', '21345678', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Y-m-d', strtotime(1991/5/12));', '21345678', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')' at line 2'

Comment: try giving input 1991-5-12 and change the value in sql syntax as $dob1 instead of $dob